# Cross widget communication in ipywidgets (custom widget in jupyter lab)

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, jupyterhub, jupyter-irkernel

We are creating a custom widget for spreadsheets inside the jupyter notebook.
We have support for cell references in the spreadsheets.
We want to implement a functionality where its possible to reference another sheet cell (cross-sheet referencing).
For this, we need the ability to communicate to other custom widget instance using messages and ability to listen for the messages. We want some guidance around it. Which functionality of ipywidget can we use to achieve this?
Is it possible to notify another widget instance about an event and send message?

There is not much documentation/guidance for cross widget communication ([Link to documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)).
I tried looking up and reading the source code of [ipywidgets](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets).
The custom widget class extends from DOMWidget which extens from Widget class.
There is `send(self, content, buffers=None)` method but this only sends the message to the front-end. There is no API to send the message to a different communication channel of different widget instance.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/ipywidgets-cross-widget-communication/21132?u=fomightez) with no acknowledgement.    
Those interested should also check there.